# Alias for Tetris/Executing elisp file

Tags: emacs, alias

So there is a Tetris program embedded in emacs. One of the ways to open it is to open emacs, hit F10, then t, then g, then Shift T, but that seems like a lot of work to just start a game of Tetris. I'd like to make an alias or function so that I can just type `tetris` and that'll start a new game.

The Tetris program is a .elc file (compiled elisp). I checked the emacs man page and I've tried a few commands, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. Here's what I've tried:

```
emacs --script tetris
```

Which threw the error `Cannot open load file: /usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/play/tetris`

So then I tried

```
emacs --script tetris.elc
```

which didn't throw any errors, but also failed to start Tetris. Then I tried invoking it with `-l` like so

```
emacs -l tetris.elc
```

and that started emacs, but again failed to start Tetris. Is there a way to pass an argument to emacs to start the program in emacs or could one of these commands be modified to execute the program directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
emacs -f tetris
```

to start emacs calling the `tetris` function (see [command line options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments) for emacs).

If you are already inside emacs, type <kbd>M-x tetris</kbd> where the M is either pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or holding Alt, Command, Option (depends on your platform).